# Get jQuery to process checkbox click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, unobtrusive-javascript

I understand that this question may get closed for being duplicate (sorry if it is), but in my particular case, there may be a different problem for the functionality not working as desired, then it was in other similar questions.

Suppose we have a markup:

```
<div>
   <label for="IsRecurring">Is Recurring</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="IsRecurring" name="IsRecurring" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="IsRecurring" type="hidden" value="false" />            
</div>

<div id="schedulerTypesList" style="display:none">
    <div>
        <label for="ScheduleTypeId">Schedule</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="hidden" name="ScheduleTypeId" id="ScheduleTypeId" value="" />

        <ul id="ScheduleTypeIdlist" >
            <li>Once a weel</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a JS attached in the document.ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#IsRecurring').click(function () {        
        var thisCheck = $(this);
        if (thischeck.is(':checked'))
            $('#schedulerTypesList').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#schedulerTypesList').hide();
        })
    });
```

[Demo in JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4DqXv/15/)

Why checkbox click event isn't toggling the display of a div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues !!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IsRecurring').click(function() {
        var thisCheck = $(this);
        if (thisCheck.is(':checked')) { // added this closing bracket
            $('#schedulerTypesList').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#schedulerTypesList').hide();
        } // added this closing bracket
    });
});
```

Missing bracket after the `if` and `thischeck` instead of `thisCheck` and added correct closing brackets. Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/4DqXv/18/

Comment: Yep, me being a dumbo =) Thank you.